# ObservableCollection not Sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing an MVVM application but I am having trouble with an Observable Collection.
The ObservableCollection is held in the view model as:

```
private ObservableCollection<Participant> _initiativeList;
public ObservableCollection<Participant> InitiativeList
{
    get { return _initiativeList; }
    set
    {
        _initiativeList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("InitiativeList");
    }
}
```

In the XAML I have a list box :

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lvInitiativeList"
              DockPanel.Dock="Top"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource InitiativeListCollection}}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ParticipantDisplayPanel}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedParticipant}"/>
```

The collectionViewSource it uses is:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=InitiativeList, Mode=OneWay}"
                      x:Key="InitiativeListCollection">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="InitiativeScore" Direction="Descending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

and the Item Template is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ParticipantDisplayPanel">
    <uc:ParticipantDisplayPanel/>
</DataTemplate>
```

the ParticipantDisplayPanel is a UserControl defined as:

```
<UserControl x:Class="InitiativeList.View.UserControls.ParticipantDisplayPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InitiativeList.View.UserControls">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Resources\CommonStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Resources\ConverterDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=ActionState, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BorderHighlight}}"  
            BorderThickness="3"
            CornerRadius="10"
            Background="{Binding Path=Kind, Mode=OneTime, Converter={StaticResource KindColor}}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Width="450"
                    Height="50"
                    Background="Transparent">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    CornerRadius="25"
                    Background="#FF8040">
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbInitiative"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="30"
                       Text="{Binding Path=InitiativeScore, 
                                      Mode=OneWay, 
                                      Converter={StaticResource InitiativeScore}}"/>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbName"
                       Background="Transparent"
                       Width="250"
                       Height="25"
                       FontFamily="Ariel"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       FontSize="20"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Condition"
                       Background="Transparent"
                       Width="100"
                       Height="25"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Condition, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="2"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    CornerRadius="25"
                    Background="{Binding Path=Healthiness, Mode=OneWay, 
                                                              Converter={StaticResource HPBackground}}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="tbHitPoints"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="25"
                           Text="{Binding Path=CurrentHitPoints, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

When I add items to the observable collection the items appear in the ListBox, and when I update properties of the elements the ParticipantDisplayPanels update to reflect the changed data.  However the collection does not sort in response to these changes, unless I specifically call OnPropertyChanged for the list, something I was expecting to be done as part of the function of the ObservableCollection, or at least through the Set code on the InitiativeList Property.
It feels wrong to have to pepper the OnPropertyChanged calls throughout the code. Am I doing something wrong? all my searches on the internet haven't turned up an example of an Observable Collection that I can relate to how I've written my code.

Any pointers as to what is going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your UI List element is bound to the list so you need a notification that the list as whole has changed, not just that an element add/removed. You'll need to raise an event when the previous sort order should be invalidated.

Comment: Your CollectionViewSource binding doesn't have an UpdateSourceTrigger specified. Is there a reason? That may be your problem.

Comment: Does your Participant implement property changed? Other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: J Steward - I thought that's what I'm currently doing that by explicitly calling OnPropertyChanged?
Tronald - Adding an UpdateSourceTrigger of OnPropertyChanged has no effect.
Joel - Yes it does, and indeed the individual bits of data update fine - it just doesnt seem to trigger the sorting

Comment: I've used this type of sorting many times, I see that you've bound InitiativeScore in the subcontrol as well as have a converter on it. What type is InitiativeScore? if its not a builtin type, does it IComparer?

Comment: It’s an int Joel

Answer (score 0):

I want to implement some custom sorting on Observable collection and I did it like below and then bind:

ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionView}"...

```
List<SortDescription> SortDescriptions = new List<SortDescription>();

SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Field1", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Field2", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Field3", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Field4", ListSortDirection.Ascending));


CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
public ICollectionView CollectionView
{
    get
    {
        collectionViewSource.Source = <YourObservableCollection>;
        if (SortDescriptions != null)
        {
            foreach (SortDescription sd in SortDescriptions)
            {
                collectionViewSource.View.SortDescriptions.Add(sd);
            }
        }

        collectionViewSource.View.Refresh();
        return collectionViewSource.View;        
    }
}
```